# non-central chi-square probability and non-centrality parameter

Tags: r

How can I get the value of the non-centrality parameter that gives a probability of exactly 0.9 for different critical values and degrees of freedom?

For example, with the significance level = 0.05 and 1 degree of freedom (critical value = 3.84), the ncp must be equal to 10.50742 in order to get a probability of 0.9:

```
1 - pchisq(3.841459, 1, 10.50742)
[1] 0.9
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rearrange terms in: 1 - pchisq(3.841459, 1, 10.50742) = 0.9 and wrap abs around the result to construct a minimization function:

```
 optim( 1, function(x) abs(pchisq(3.841459, 1, x)  - 0.1) )
#-------
$par
[1] 10.50742

$value
[1] 1.740301e-08

$counts
function gradient 
      56       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

To do a sensitivity analysis, you can serially alter the values of the other parameters:

```
for( crit.val in seq(2.5, 3.5, by=0.1)) {
         print( optim( 1, 
                function(x) abs(pchisq(crit.val, 1, x)  - 0.1), 
                method="Brent" , lower=0, upper=20)$par)}
[1] 8.194852
[1] 8.375145
[1] 8.553901
[1] 8.731204
[1] 8.907135
[1] 9.081764
[1] 9.255156
[1] 9.427372
[1] 9.598467
[1] 9.768491
[1] 9.937492
```

Comment: please help me .I need to generate random numbers from chi squared distribution with the rt function .In fact the scenario as follows .i must generate first of all random variables fron a density function f. X~f(x) and random variables from the shifted distribution function means Y~f(x-delta) ,delta is the shift .I have tried the following : x<-rt(10,3) and y<-rt(10,3)+2 ,Here we have 10 numbers 3 degrees of freedom and delta =2 but when i take a look to some scientefic litterature and R i find

Comment: peeople are talking about non centraliy parameter when we want to make shifting for chi squae as well for t distributon.Now my question is how to express shift using noncentraliy parameter ,since it is the only correst method

Comment: @ZB I don't see this as a simple follow on to this question or answer. I do think there is a close relationship between the chi-square and t distributions that arises from particular choices for integration over the sampling distribution of Normally distributed  variates under particular assumptions. I don't immediately see how to go from `rt` to `rchisq`. I think you will find that non-central t distributions are NOT the same as a shifted t. The first is asymmetric around x=ncp,  while the latter is symmetric around the x=0 axis.

Comment: pleaase understand me ,Please forget the chi-square i am talking about the non central t distribution. in order to conduct power analysis , my alternative hypothesis was that Y is shifted sample generated from rt

Comment: just change the first statement to  "I need to generate random numbers from t- distribution with the rt function" . I have made mistake when I was writing .

Comment: @IRFTM all the litterature that i have encountered are talking about non centrality parameter in order to test the alternative hypothesis Y~f(x-delta)

Comment: Generating random t draws with the rt function should not be difficult. The third parameter Is named “ncp”.

Comment: yes i do know but i want that the ncp correspends to a shift of 2

Comment: If you are not setting ncp=2, then what sort of “shift” are you talking about?

Comment: i think when we want to shift with 2 we do not set ncp to 2 i think another value

Comment: Still do not know what is shifting. How will we know when the right value for ncp has been found?

Comment: @IRFTM this my big problem.I have contacted Rand wilcox himself per email through the R-help blog ,he does not have enough time to give detailed answer but he says to me that rt(m,df=n)+a is false method to shift with an amount of a .But ,one must use the non central t distribution. Which value for ncp??!! I do not know!!!

Comment: Your suggestion (`rt(m,df=n)+a`)was to use the central-t and you were told it was incorrect (although I do not know what your actual question was to Dr. Wilcox)). I was asking whether using a non-central t random variate, i.e.  `rt(m, df=n, ncp=a)` ,would meet your as yet unclear purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently developing a package, [NCdistributions](https://github.com/stla/NCdistributions), which provides a function doing exactly what you want:

```r
> library(NCdistributions)
> find_chisq_ncp(nu = 1, q = 3.841459, p = 0.1)
[1] 10.50742
```